# Does je le/la sais exist since je sais exists

Tags: verbes

I think 'je sais'  means 'I know'  or 'I know it'. Since it also means 'I know it', does 'je le/la sais' exist? Or is it both possible?

Comment: Autocorrect, I'm not native English

Comment: No problem !  Have you looked at a dictionary ? [je le sais](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/je%20le%20sais)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Je sais** means "I know". Normally you expect something behind (je sais + quelque chose), so it is completely correct to translate "I know it" with "je le sais" (skipping **le** is quite frequent in spoken language, but "je le sais" is the right construction.) Note that the **it** will be translated as "le" and not as "la", but "la" is possible in some cases, e.g. :

> Je sais qu'elle est intelligente.
>
> --> Je **le** sais. (**le** replaces "that she is clever")
>
> --> Je **la** sais intelligente. (**la** replaces "she")